# How does Beta Minus decay result in a more stable nucleus if it decreases the Binding energy per nucleon?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, binding-energy

I understand that beta minus decay occurs when a radioisotope has too many neutrons and hence the Strong Nuclear attractive Force (SNF) overpowers the Coulombic repulsive force.

However, doesn't Beta minus result in a decrease in Binding Energy per Nucleon (BEN),which is an indicator of nuclear stability?

During Beta minus decay, a neutron is converted to a proton, electron and anti-electron neutrino, with the latter 2 being released. However, as the nucleus has an extra proton and one less neutron, whilst the atomic mass will remain roughly the same and hence the SNF will remain roughly the same, doesn't this mean the Coulombic repulsive force increases? As a result, isn't the force holding the nucleus together lower, ie its binding energy would decrease? and since BEN = binding energy / mass number, we are essentially just dividing a smaller binding energy by the same mass number, resulting in a lower BEN.

As BEN is an indicator of nucleus stability, doesn't this mean that the nucleus is actually less stable, which contradicts the fact it should be more stable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think a conceptual picture involving forces is helpful here. In that picture you would end up having to say that the most stable nucleus is made entirely of neutrons!

What it neglects is the Pauli Exclusion Principle (PEP) and the inability to pack as many neutrons as you like into the lowest energy quantum states in the nuclei.

Better to think of nucleons occupying quantised energy levels within the nuclear potential. The neutrons and protons separately obey the PEP and fill up energy levels in a manner similar to electrons filling the various shells in an atom (an example is shown below). Since all nucleons experience a similar strong nuclear force and similar nuclear potential, then the energy of these shells is comparable for the separate proton and neutron populations, so nuclei end up with the lowest overall energy (i.e the biggest binding energy) by having *roughly* equal numbers of protons and neutrons$^1$. If there is an imbalance in numbers, then the "extra" neutrons may occupy higher energy shells than the highest energy protons and thus greater stability can be reached by them decaying into protons that can still occupy unfilled but lower energy spaces in the proton shells.

[image: Nuclear energy levels]

The above qualitatively explains why there is a locus of neutron/proton ratio that defines a maximum in the binding energy per nucleon for a given number of nucleons.

$^1$ Note that because of Coulomb repulsion, the potentials for the neutrons and protons and therefore the energies of these shells are *not* the same. When the number of nucleons is large, then the maximum energies of the neutrons and protons are comparable when there are somewhat more neutrons than protons.

Answer (score 0):

“Binding energy per nucleon” is only useful in the approximation where neutrons and protons have the same mass. Consider the decay of a free neutron to a free proton, where the binding energy of the free nucleon is exactly zero before and after the decay.

What matters in beta decay is the total mass-energy of the parent and daughter nuclei. These are usefully tabulated as [mass excesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_excess); [this NNDC database](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/indx_sigma.jsp) gives mass excesses for neutral atoms and some excited isomeric states.